# I can't read a csv file in Python. The result has many rows instead of cells

Tags: python, csv

I'm a newbie in Python. I'm trying to download and read a CSV from a url. I have this code:

```
import csv
import requests


url = "http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/observacion/ultimosdatos_8178D_datos-horarios.csv?k=clm&l=8178D&datos=det&w=0&f=temperatura&x=h24"
r = requests.get(url)
contenido = r.content
assert isinstance(contenido, basestring)
sin3lineas = '\r\n'.join( contenido.split('\r\n')[3:])
sin3lineasutf8 = sin3lineas.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')

print sin3lineasutf8

#cr = csv.reader(sin3lineasutf8,quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=False)
cr = csv.reader(sin3lineasutf8)
for row in cr:
    print row,
    print len(row)
```

And the result of the reading is:

```
"Fecha y hora oficial","Temperatura (ºC)","Velocidad del viento (km/h)","Dirección del viento","Racha (km/h)","Dirección de racha","Precipitación (mm)","Presión (hPa)","Tendencia (hPa)","Humedad (%)"
"19/02/2016 00:00","4.4","0","Calma","6","Nordeste","0.0","937.0","1.0","88"
"18/02/2016 02:00","4.3","10","Oeste","25","Oeste","0.0","935.3","-0.2","60"
...
"18/02/2016 01:00","4.2","12","Oeste","30","Noroeste","0.0","935.7","0.0","58"

['Fecha y hora oficial'] 1
['', ''] 2
['Temperatura (\xc2\xbaC)'] 1
['', ''] 2
['Velocidad del viento (km/h)'] 1
['', ''] 2
['Direcci\xc3\xb3n del viento'] 1
['', ''] 2
...
[] 0
[] 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The readed CSV has many rows instead of cells, but I don't know why.
I tried many parameters of the function csv.read, but no one of them solves the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the `response.text` into a *buffer* worked for me:

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

import requests


url = "http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/observacion/ultimosdatos_8178D_datos-horarios.csv?k=clm&l=8178D&datos=det&w=0&f=temperatura&x=h24"
r = requests.get(url)

buffer = StringIO(r.text)
cr = csv.reader(buffer)
for row in cr:
    print(row)
```

Prints:

```
['Albacete']
['Actualizado: viernes', ' 19 febrero 2016 a las 00:42 hora oficial']
[]
['Fecha y hora oficial', 'Temperatura (ºC)', 'Velocidad del viento (km/h)', 'Dirección del viento', 'Racha (km/h)', 'Dirección de racha', 'Precipitación (mm)', 'Presión (hPa)', 'Tendencia (hPa)', 'Humedad (%)']
['19/02/2016 00:00', '4.4', '0', 'Calma', '6', 'Nordeste', '0.0', '937.0', '1.0', '88']
['18/02/2016 23:00', '4.7', '0', 'Calma', '5', 'Nordeste', '0.0', '936.9', '1.5', '86']
['18/02/2016 22:00', '4.7', '0', 'Calma', '5', 'Nordeste', '0.0', '936.7', '1.9', '84']
['18/02/2016 21:00', '5.3', '0', 'Calma', '5', 'Nordeste', '0.0', '936.0', '1.8', '83']
['18/02/2016 20:00', '5.9', '0', 'Calma', '5', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '935.4', '1.3', '82']
['18/02/2016 19:00', '6.4', '0', 'Calma', '10', 'Oeste', '0.0', '934.8', '1.2', '77']
['18/02/2016 18:00', '6.9', '2', 'Noroeste', '13', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '934.2', '0.6', '74']
['18/02/2016 17:00', '7.1', '4', 'Noroeste', '12', 'Oeste', '0.0', '934.1', '0.3', '73']
['18/02/2016 16:00', '7.2', '3', 'Noroeste', '12', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '933.6', '-0.7', '73']
['18/02/2016 15:00', '7.0', '4', 'Noroeste', '14', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '933.6', '-1.3', '77']
['18/02/2016 14:00', '6.6', '2', 'Noroeste', '16', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '933.8', '-1.1', '79']
['18/02/2016 13:00', '6.3', '5', 'Noroeste', '18', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '934.3', '-0.5', '82']
['18/02/2016 12:00', '5.5', '5', 'Noroeste', '14', 'Oeste', '0.0', '934.9', '0.1', '87']
['18/02/2016 11:00', '4.6', '3', 'Noroeste', '9', 'Oeste', '0.0', '934.9', '1.2', '95']
['18/02/2016 10:00', '3.4', '0', 'Calma', '5', 'Nordeste', '0.0', '934.8', '0.6', '95']
['18/02/2016 09:00', '3.1', '0', 'Calma', '5', 'Norte', '0.0', '934.8', '0.7', '94']
['18/02/2016 08:00', '3.4', '0', 'Calma', '5', 'Oeste', '0.0', '933.7', '-0.2', '91']
['18/02/2016 07:00', '3.5', '0', 'Calma', '10', 'Oeste', '0.0', '934.2', '-0.2', '88']
['18/02/2016 06:00', '3.6', '3', 'Noroeste', '15', 'Oeste', '0.0', '934.1', '-0.9', '86']
['18/02/2016 05:00', '3.9', '5', 'Oeste', '18', 'Sudoeste', '0.0', '933.9', '-1.4', '73']
['18/02/2016 04:00', '4.1', '7', 'Oeste', '17', 'Oeste', '0.0', '934.4', '-1.3', '68']
['18/02/2016 03:00', '4.2', '7', 'Oeste', '23', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '935.0', '-0.6', '64']
['18/02/2016 02:00', '4.3', '10', 'Oeste', '25', 'Oeste', '0.0', '935.3', '-0.2', '60']
['18/02/2016 01:00', '4.2', '12', 'Oeste', '30', 'Noroeste', '0.0', '935.7', '0.0', '58']
```

If you want to skip the first 4 rows to get to the actual data, you can use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

for row in islice(cr, 4, None):
    print(row)
```